# 404 for all routes in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

#### My Problem

I'm getting 404 for all routes, my flask api is running, and when i run it, the api receive the request and log it, but, it give 404 http status for every request;
`shell
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2018 16:49:12] "GET /api/ping/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2018 16:50:10] "POST /api/blur/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

#### My code

I' have a class `Server`, this Server class receive a `Flask app` and run it:

```
from jsonmerge import merge

class Server():
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.__app = app
        self.__config = #snip
        #snip

    def start(self, options=None):
        #snip

        self.__app.run(debug=self.__config["debug"], 
        port=self.__config["server"]["port"], host=self.__config["server"]["ip"])
```

and i have my run.py that run my aplication:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    srv = Server(app)
    srv.start(config)
```

when I print my `self.__app` infromations, my output is:

```
<Flask 'appfly.app'>

<Config {'ENV': 'production', 'DEBUG': False, 'TESTING': False, 'PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS': None, 'PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION': None, 'SECRET_KEY': None, 'PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=31), 'USE_X_SENDFILE': False, 'SERVER_NAME': None, 'APPLICATION_ROOT': '/', 'SESSION_COOKIE_NAME': 'session', 'SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_PATH': None, 'SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY': True, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE': False, 'SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE': None, 'SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST': True, 'MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH': None, 'SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT': datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200), 'TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS': None, 'TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS': False, 'EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING': False, 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME': 'http', 'JSON_AS_ASCII': True, 'JSON_SORT_KEYS':True, 'JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR': False, 'JSONIFY_MIMETYPE': 'application/json', 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD': None, 'MAX_COOKIE_SIZE': 4093}>

Map([<Rule '/api/ping' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> ping>,
 <Rule '/api/blur' (POST, OPTIONS) -> blur>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, HEAD, OPTIONS) -> static>])
```

look, my `url_map` list all my routes, the `api/ping` route and `api/blur` route is there.

#### My faill solutions

many stackover flow responses say to change the config["server_name"] but it doesnt works
I already tried set SERVER_NAME to 0.0.0.0:9000,localhost:9000, 127.0.0.1:9000

I make an flask tutorial to verify the SERVER_NAME and it is None

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
print(app.config["SERVER_NAME"])
#app.run(...)
```

`> None`

I tried set the to `Flask ENV` to `development` but it doest works to:

```
self.__app.config["ENV"]='development'
```

#### how it works before

I aways used Flask in this way and aways worked fine:

---> app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Routes files
from app.presentation.routes import ping
from app.presentation.routes import rg as rg_scan

# Routes rules
app.add_url_rule('/api/ping', 'Ping', ping.route, methods=['GET'])
app.add_url_rule('/api/rg', 'RG', rg_scan.route, methods=['POST'])
print('API is running...')
```

---> run.py

```
from app import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=9000, host='0.0.0.0')
```

but now i wanna do it in a diferent way, i wanna use my Server Class to start my flask api.

#### Environment

- Python version: 3.7.0
- Flask version: 1.0.2
- OS Version: Manjaro Linux 18.0.0-rc

Comment: What's with all the double underscores? That invokes name mangling

Comment: Sorry, i dont get your comment, are you saying abot the `self.__app`?

Comment: `GET /api/ping/` but you define route `/api/ping`. The trailing slash is not just ornament, it's fully part of the route. Unless you somehow map `/api/ping/` to `/api/ping` in your code, they are distinct urls.

Comment: tks, it resolved my problem, but I can ignore it? because in others nodejs frameworks (i was nodejs dev before), it isn't a problem

Comment: If your JS framework likes trailing slashes, the simplest way would be to use trailing slashes in your routes as well. Alternatively, most frameworks can be configured to not add trailing slashes. Lastly, Flask has some config options that will make it redirect automatically - but that option is not a good idea, as it will incur 2 requests for every access.